# How do I computationally slice an audio file into small samples?

Tags: macos, audio, batch

I need to cut audio files into small samples of even length. What I need is basically a batch processor for audio that does it and names the slices numerically. I'm using OSX and have found [Audio Splitter](http://www.macsome.com/audio-splitter-mac/index.html). The shortest possible sample length with it is 1 second though, too long for my purpose. Anyone know an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excellent sound converter SoX (also named 'the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation') [works on OS X](http://sox.darwinports.com/), so I hope this script will help you:

```
#!/bin/sh

N=0
START=0
LENGTH=8000
COUNT=100
INPUT=input.mp3
OUTPUT=output-X.wav

for i in `jot ${COUNT}`; do
    echo "Trimming ${START}+${LENGTH}"
    sox ${INPUT} `echo ${OUTPUT} | sed s/X/${N}/` trim ${START}s ${LENGTH}s
    N=`expr ${N} + 1`
    START=`expr ${START} + ${LENGTH}`
done
```

All lengths are in samples (you can also specify time in 'HH:MM:SS.ddd' format, check SoX manpage); it reads INPUT file and produces files named output-0.wav, output-1.wav and so on.

Comment: okay this sounds great, exactly what i need.
i've installed SoX, however when i execute run the script i get "line 15: seq: command not found"
(i'm a complete command line noob)

Comment: "seq" is GNU. For OSX or BSD you want "jot".  
  e.g. for i in \`jot ${COUNT}\`; do

Comment: Fixed the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=input.wav
OUTPUT=output-X.wav

N=0
START=0
LENGTH=0.05 # length in ms (to use samples you should add s suffix to commandline trim Xs Ys and s flag for soxi)
TOTAL_LENGTH=`soxi -D ${INPUT}`

while [ $(echo "$START < $TOTAL_LENGTH"|bc) -eq 1 ]; do
    echo "Trimming from ${START} of ${TOTAL_LENGTH}"
    sox ${INPUT} `echo ${OUTPUT} | sed s/X/${N}/` trim ${START} ${LENGTH}
    N=$(($N+1))
    START=`echo "$START + $LENGTH"|bc`
done
```

The difference is:

- Script works with `ms` rather than with `samples`
- The amount of output files is automatically detected by `INPUT` length